# Win11/Ubuntu 20.04 Dual Boot: Cannot start Windows anymore from Grub Menu

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, windows, grub-efi

So, a couple of months ago I installed Ubuntu as my second OS alongside Windows 10 (recently updated to Windows 11), and it worked without any major issues. Finally, I had a great work station for scientific programs for uni and a gaming station for my spare time... up until yesterday.
Today, I tried to open Windows from the Grub Menu as usual. However, instead of actually booting, it just brought me back to the very same Grub Menu, no matter how often I tried. Ubuntu starts normally, but Windows doesn't work for some reason.
I installed Ubuntu on a partition on my 2nd SSD. I can still access my Windows files through the File Explorer, but I can't get the OS running.
I viewed the menu entries via Grub Customizer:

Windows Boot Manager (auf /dev/sdb2):

```
    insmod part_gpt
insmod fat
set root='hd1,gpt2'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt2  E0E5-1D49
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root E0E5-1D49
fi
chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
```

The Grub configuration file itself looks like this (commented lines and custum design ignored):

```
...
GRUB_DEFAULT="Windows Boot Manager (auf /dev/sdb2)"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="hidden"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="20"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

...
```

I recently updated from Win10 to Win11, without any issues. I could open and run both systems whenever I wanted to, without the need to reconfigure anything. Now, however, only Ubuntu seems to work.
I've tried to google this problem, but so far I haven't found a solution (perhaps I wasn't able to articulate myself correctly). I'd be glad if anyone with more expertise could help me with this.

The partition for Win11 (/dev/sdb2) is mounted (unless I overlooked something). If it helps, I'm using an MSI mainboard.

EDIT: Selecting Windows from the Boot Menu after pressing F11 during the start up doesn't work either, I just get thrown back to the menu (Ubuntu works fine nonetheless)

GParted Screenshot (hope you don't mind that it's all in German:

[image]

Comment: The first thing to try is boot Windows directly in UEFI settings > Boot.

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't worked out so far. I tried to boot it from the menu right after pressing F11 during the start-up. I also tried using `sudo update-grub` to no avail.

Comment: Ah right, my bad. Posted the GParted screenshot and removed the ESP one.

Comment: If it doesn't boot directly then it won't and couldn't from Grub, obviously. You need to repair the Windows installation and that is off-topic here.

Comment: Alright then, thanks tho!